# How do i use MUI React components inside an iframe?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, iframe, material-ui

Similar to this screenshot taken from the Material UI website, I want to create this 'box' that will hold my iframe contents, which includes the navBar, menu drawer etc. However, I want to make use of material UI's components for the navBar and menu drawer. How should i approach this?

My current issue is that my nav bar stays within my iframe, but it seems like the drawer will slide out from my browser window instead of the iframe box.

I need to embed another iframe into this iframe, that will hold my text content.[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example of what you described
Final result:
https://react18-mui-srfhzb.stackblitz.io/

Main Page
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react18-mui-srfhzb?file=Drawer.jsx,App.tsx

Iframe Content
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react18-mui-c69cpe?file=Drawer.jsx,App.tsx

[image]

Code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Drawer from '@mui/material/Drawer';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

export default function TemporaryDrawer() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const toggleDrawer = (newOpen) => () => {
    setOpen(newOpen);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={toggleDrawer(true)}>Open drawer</Button>
      <Drawer open={open} onClose={toggleDrawer(false)}>
        Example Drawer
      </Drawer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Usage:

```
<Box sx={{ width: '90%', margin: 'auto' }}>
  <iframe
    src="your-iframe-page-url"
    title="description"></iframe>
</Box>
```

Comment: I do not want the iframe to display the parent content

Comment: @SarahAlexa This is just an example. To not show the parent content you need to make a separate page and put its link in the iframe. What's your code that doesn't work?

Comment: @SarahAlexa I updated the links accordingly to not show the parent content.